# Force replication for all AD Domain Controllers

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to correct an issue with the below Powershell script to force AD replication from one AD to all its replication partners.

The Goal of the script is to be able to run it from the workstation without the AD PowerShell or RSAT installed.

```
$forest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.forest]::getcurrentforest()
$Domains = $forest.domains

Foreach ($Domain in $domains) {
    $dcs = $Domain.FindAllDomainControllers()
    write-host $($Domain.name)

    foreach ($dc in $dcs) {
        $pingtest = $(Test-Connection $($dc.name) -Quiet -Count 2)
        $DCIP = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($dc.name)
        $HostnameByIP = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostbyAddress($dc.Name.ToString())
        write-host "DC Hostname: $($HostnameByIP) - $($DCIP) up : $pingtest"
        
        #only get replication info if server is up
        if ($pingtest) {
            #get all replication infomation
            $repNeighbors = $dc.GetAllReplicationNeighbors()
            foreach ($rep in $repNeighbors) {
                #if the last replication result is -gt 0 it is an error
                if ($rep.LastSyncResult -gt 0) {
                    #add code here to react to an error
                    write-host "$($rep.SourceServer) to $($dc.name) replication error"
                }
                else {
                    # If no issue on the AD replication, 
                    # then force the synch from where the current AD RDP session is running, 
                    # so it is replicating to all AD domain controllers, without waiting for 15 minutes.
                    #
                    # Calculate the KCC to determine whatchanges is made on the current AD domain controller:
                    repadmin /kcc $_.Name
                    # Replicate from the current AD domain controller where the changes has been made:
                    # repadmin /syncall /A(ll partitions) P(ush) e(nterprise, cross sites) d(istinguished names) parameters $dc.Name
                    repadmin /syncall $dc.Name /APed
                    #
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception calling "GetHostByAddress" with "1" argument(s): "An invalid IP address was specified."
At line:11 char:9
+         $HostnameByIP = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostbyAddress($dc.Name.T ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

Comment: why are you trying to get the host by address when you are using the name? this ... >>> `$HostnameByIP = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostbyAddress($dc.Name.ToString())` <<< means you are feeding the method a name  ... but it requires an IP address.

Comment: OK, so how do I get the Hostname without the FQDN ?

Comment: this >>> `$DCIP = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($dc.name)` <<< otta give you the IP, then you otta be able to use _that_ in your `GetHostbyAddress()` call.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, sadly no, it shows like: DC Hostname: System.Net.IPHostEntry instead.

Comment: that is because you failed to extract the IPv4 address from the variable. [*grin*] the following would give you JUST the IPv4 address >>> `([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses('LocalHost')).Where({$_.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork'})[0].IpAddressToString` <<< do remember to replace my `LocalHost` with your dc name ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, thank you for the suggestion, yes it is also working.

Comment: kool! glad that it worked for you ... [*grin*]

Comment: No worries man, you've been helpful to this community :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

```
HostnameByIP = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostbyAddress($DCIP.IPAddressToString)
```

but that assumes that your host will return only one address.

Nevertheless, your $DC variable already has a `Name` and an `IPAddress` property that you can probably use instead of going and looking for it again from your DNS server/appliance.